# Redmine Web application could not be started

Tags: ruby, passenger, redmine

My redmine stoped working
Now all that i see is:

```
 Web application could not be started
    An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup     back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
    Raw process output:

    (empty)
    Error ID
    bed958bb
    Application root
    /usr/local/www/redmine
    Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
    production
    Ruby interpreter command
    /usr/local/bin/ruby19
    User and groups
    uid=80(www) gid=80(www) groups=80(www)
    Environment variables
    SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.2.29 (FreeBSD) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.53 PHP/5.3.29 with Suhosin-Patch     mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-freebsd DAV/2
    SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
    SERVER_NAME=rm.i.vvtf.ru
    SERVER_ADMIN=it@vvtf.ru
    SERVER_ADDR=192.168.10.202
    SERVER_PORT=443
    REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.10.45
    REMOTE_PORT=48936
    REQUEST_METHOD=GET
    QUERY_STRING=
    HTTPS=on
    DOCUMENT_ROOT=/usr/local/www/redmine/public/
    REQUEST_URI=/
    UNIQUE_ID=VDTOd8CoCsoAADX0RNAAAAAA
    SSL_TLS_SNI=rm.i.vvtf.ru
PASSENGER_APP_ENV=production
NODE_ENV=production
WSGI_ENV=production
RACK_ENV=production
RAILS_ENV=production
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/node_lib
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
IN_PASSENGER=1
PWD=/usr/local/www/redmine
HOME=/nonexistent
SHELL=/usr/sbin/nologin
LOGNAME=www
USER=www
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR=/tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.nQowvt7keA
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
RC_PID=13777
Ulimits
cpu time               (seconds, -t)  unlimited
file size           (512-blocks, -f)  unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d)  524288
stack size              (kbytes, -s)  65536
core file size      (512-blocks, -c)  unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m)  unlimited
locked memory           (kbytes, -l)  131072
max user processes              (-u)  5547
open files                      (-n)  28890
virtual mem size        (kbytes, -v)  unlimited
swap limit              (kbytes, -w)  unlimited
sbsize                   (bytes, -b)  unlimited
pseudo-terminals                (-p)  unlimited
System metrics
------------- General -------------
Kernel version    : 10.0-RELEASE-p9
Uptime            : 52m 39s
Load averages     : 0.99%, 0.83%, 0.81%

------------- CPU -------------
Number of CPUs    :    2
Average CPU usage :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 1           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle
  CPU 2           :   0%  --   0% user,   0% nice,   0% system, 100% idle

------------- Memory -------------
RAM total         :   1003 MB
RAM used          :    461 MB (46%)
RAM free          :    541 MB
Swap total        :   2560 MB
Swap used         :      0 MB (0%)
Swap free         :   2560 MB

General Ruby interpreter information
RUBY_VERSION = 1.9.3
RUBY_PLATFORM = i386-freebsd10
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 1.8.29
RubyGems paths = ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9"]
Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
DESTDIR = 
MAJOR = 1
MINOR = 9
TEENY = 1
PATCHLEVEL = 547
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c -o root -g wheel
EXEEXT = 
prefix = /usr/local
ruby_install_name = ruby19
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby19
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby19
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby-1.9.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
vendorhdrdir = /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9//vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9//site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9/
UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
configure_args =  '--with-rubyhdrdir=/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9/' '--with-rubylibprefix=/usr/local/lib/ruby' '--docdir=/usr/local/share/doc/ruby19' '--with-soname=ruby19' '--program-prefix=' '--program-suffix=19' '--enable-shared' '--enable-pthread' '--disable-rpath' '--with-ruby-version=minor' '--with-sitedir=/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby' '--with-vendordir=/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby' '--disable-install-capi' '--disable-install-rdoc' '--disable-libedit' '--with-readline-prefix=/usr/local' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--mandir=/usr/local/man' '--infodir=/usr/local/info/' '--build=i386-portbld-freebsd10' 'build_alias=i386-portbld-freebsd10' 'CC=cc' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing' 'LDFLAGS= -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib' 'LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -pthread' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include' 'CXX=c++' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing' 'CPP=cpp'
vendordir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitedir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
ruby_version = 1.9
sitearch = i386-freebsd10
arch = i386-freebsd10
RI_BASE_NAME = ri
ridir = /usr/local/share/ri
rubylibprefix = /usr/local/lib/ruby
MAKEFILES = Makefile
PLATFORM_DIR = 
THREAD_MODEL = pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
EXPORT_PREFIX = 
COMMON_HEADERS = 
COMMON_MACROS = 
COMMON_LIBS = 
MAINLIBS = -pthread 
ENABLE_SHARED = yes
DLDLIBS =  -lc
SOLIBS = -lexecinfo -lcrypt -lm -L/usr/local/lib -pthread
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -lruby19
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -lruby19-static
LIBRUBYARG = -lruby19
LIBRUBY = libruby19.so.19
LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby19.so
LIBRUBY_SO = libruby19.so.19
LIBRUBY_A = libruby19-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
rubyw_install_name = 
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby19.so.19
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED = cc -shared
EXTDLDFLAGS = 
warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration
debugflags = 
optflags = -O3
cxxflags =  -O3  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cflags =  -O3  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration
cppflags = -I/usr/local/include
NULLCMD = :
INSTALLDOC = nodoc
CAPITARGET = nodoc
RDOCTARGET = nodoc
EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
ARCHFILE = 
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
EXTOUT = .ext
PREP = miniruby
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
setup = Setup
EXTSTATIC = 
STRIP = strip
TRY_LINK = 
LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG = 
LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%s
LINK_SO = 
LIBEXT = a
DLEXT2 = 
DLEXT = so
LDSHAREDXX = c++ -shared
LDSHARED = cc -shared
CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
STATIC = 
ARCH_FLAG = 
DLDFLAGS = 
ALLOCA = 
codesign = 
POSTLINK = :
WERRORFLAG = -Werror
CHDIR = cd -P
RMALL = rm -fr
RMDIRS = rmdir -p
RMDIR = rmdir
CP = cp
RM = rm -f
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
DOXYGEN = 
DOT = 
MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA = install  -o root -g wheel -m 0644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = install  -o root -g wheel -m 555
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install  -s -o root -g wheel -m 555
SET_MAKE = 
LN_S = ln -s
NM = nm
DLLWRAP = 
WINDRES = 
OBJCOPY = :
OBJDUMP = objdump
ASFLAGS = 
AS = as
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
try_header = 
COUTFLAG = -o 
OUTFLAG = -o 
CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
GNU_LD = yes
GCC = yes
EGREP = /usr/bin/egrep
GREP = /usr/bin/grep
CPP = cpp
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing
CXX = c++
OBJEXT = o
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS = -L.  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib -rdynamic
CFLAGS = -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC
CC = cc
target_os = freebsd10
target_vendor = portbld
target_cpu = i386
target = i386-portbld-freebsd10
host_os = freebsd10
host_vendor = portbld
host_cpu = i386
host = i386-portbld-freebsd10
RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
build_os = freebsd10
build_vendor = portbld
build_cpu = i386
build = i386-portbld-freebsd10
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE = 2014-05-14
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 1.9.3
BASERUBY = ruby
target_alias = 
host_alias = 
build_alias = i386-portbld-freebsd10
LIBS = -lexecinfo -lcrypt -lm -L/usr/local/lib -pthread
ECHO_T = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_C = 
DEFS = 
mandir = /usr/local/man
localedir = /usr/local/share/locale
libdir = /usr/local/lib
psdir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby19
pdfdir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby19
dvidir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby19
htmldir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby19
infodir = /usr/local/info
docdir = /usr/local/share/doc/ruby19
oldincludedir = /usr/include
includedir = /usr/local/include
localstatedir = /usr/local/var
sharedstatedir = /usr/local/com
sysconfdir = /usr/local/etc
datadir = /usr/local/share
datarootdir = /usr/local/share
libexecdir = /usr/local/libexec
sbindir = /usr/local/sbin
bindir = /usr/local/bin
program_transform_name = s&$&19&;s&^&&
exec_prefix = /usr/local
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
PACKAGE_STRING = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 
PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
PACKAGE_NAME = 
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
SHELL = /bin/sh
rubylibdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9
archdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10
sitelibdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9
sitearchdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10
vendorlibdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9
vendorarchdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10
topdir = /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10
Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10
Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)
enumerator.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10/enc/encdb.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10/enc/trans/transdb.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems/defaults.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10/rbconfig.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems/custom_require.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10/etc.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/fileutils.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/tmpdir.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-x86-freebsd10/passenger_native_support.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10/socket.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/socket.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/thread.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpdir.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/shellwords.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10/fcntl.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/i386-freebsd10/stringio.so
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-  4.0.53/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
```

I had try to reinstall redmine, passenger, etc....
I had try to config httpd.conf - the same result.
Now it just don't work.
Always the same error (only error id is different every time).
I can show apache log file if this need.
Always the same result.

If i try in the /use/local/www/redmine/ to start rail server with "bundle exec rails server" i got this: "=> Booting WEBrick => Rails 3.2.19 application starting in development on 0.0.0.0:3000 => Call with -d to detach => Ctrl-C to shutdown server Illegal instruction (core dumped) "

HELP ME to fix it!!!

Comment: Can you launch Redmine without Passenger?

Comment: You mean use thin web server?

Comment: Not, I offer to launch Redmine without Passenger. rails server -p 80 on the Redmine folder

Comment: Don't know how to launch rail server. Maby will try when will read about it. I don't understand why it stoped to work.... Maby because i had update bash.... I think the 1 or 2 problem cause it mine - https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems. I had try to run like in the topic - bash -l -c '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/agentsSpawnPreparer /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.10/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb', but got only error 'Too few arguments'

Comment: If i try in the /use/local/www/redmine/ to start rail server with "bundle exec rails server" i got this: "=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.19 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
"

Comment: Does Redmine works correctly in this case (on http:\\localhost:3000) ?

Comment: Any other solutions????

Comment: No, it does not! As i said before, If i try in the /use/local/www/redmine/ to start rail server with "bundle exec rails server" i got this: "=> Booting WEBrick => Rails 3.2.19 application starting in development on 0.0.0.0:3000 => Call with -d to detach => Ctrl-C to shutdown server Illegal instruction (core dumped) "

Comment: BTW. if i try to create an empty DB with suck command as: rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate, i got the same error - Illegal instruction.